# Get ID from second table if is join two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need get ID from second(feed) table now I am got ID from first tabel (users). Please see image below !
[image]

Comment: Explicitly name your columns: `SELECT feed.id AS feed_id, users.id as user_id` etc. `SELECT *` is seldom a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have ID in both user and feed table so better to use following

```
select feed.ID as feed_id, feed.Picture,feed.assign,feed.comment
from feed
left join users on users.Username = feed.user
```

Then you can use as

```
$feed["feed_id"] to display
```

NOTE : You may have more fields in the feed table so add them all in the select if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *, feed.id as f_id
    from feed
    ...
```

Then in your code use `$feed['f_id']`

Answer (score 0):

what if you wrote it like this:

```
Select
F.*,
u.username
From
Feed as F
Left Join users as u on u.userid=F.userid 
order by 'f.userid'
```